# Combining video and subtitle files as one video?

Tags: video-editing, subtitles

I have a video file (in the format of .mp4, .mkv, .avi or whatever) and a subtitle file (.srt). I want to embed the subtitle file into the video file so that I have only one file - the video file in contrast to the video and the subtitle file.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Soft embedded subs that can be turned off are the way to go (might not be possible with AVI though); hard subs are really irritating and not only does adding them cause quality loss, but removing them is not possible without further significant loss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MKVtoolnix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/index.html) is another easy to use option since you already have the files you want. You can combine them into an MKV container without altering the originals in anyway. It has a nice GUI to guide you through the combination process as well.

I see user1301428 had mentioned Handbrake, which is also a very common/popular tool. I'm not as familiar with it, but if it doesn't re-encode your source AVI then it should be great.

Answer (score 27):

A free, cross-platform solution with [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), which does bitstream copy and therefore doesn't take more than a few seconds, even for large files:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i subtitles.srt -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

This works for MP4. Be aware that some subtitle formats might not automatically be compatible with the chosen output formats, so you have to change the codec after `-c:s`:

- **MP4:** Use the `mov_text` subtitle codec (as in the example above), which implements [MPEG-4 Part 17](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_17).
- **MKV:** Use `srt`, `subrip`, `ssa` or `ass`. MKV does not support `mov_text`.
- **AVI:** Very problematic with embedded subtitles. In theory they support SubRip and SSA/ASS subtitles, but only through third party software.

See Wikipedia for a [list of containers and their supported subtitle formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats#Caption_.28Subtitle.29_formats_supported).

Using dedicated video encoding programs such as Handbrake will re-encode your video, which reduces its quality and could take you *hours* to encode – this is why you should check whether the tools support copying the video and audio bitstreams.

Comment: I have found `-f srt` to be necessary sometimes, otherwise great!

Comment: In case your subtitle file is of `*.vtt` format, use `-c:s webvtt` option, like this: `ffmpeg -i input.webm -i input.vtt -c:s webvtt -c:v copy -c:a copy output.webm`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/). In the "Subtitles" tab you simply need to select the subtitles file and then launch the encoding.

Comment: This wil re-encode the video, which a) takes a lot of time and b) deteriorates the quality.

Answer (score -1):

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf subtitles=subtitle.srt out.avi
```